# How to write a Prolog solver to solve this logic problem?

Tags: prolog, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I have spent some time learning Prolog, and have some basic understanding of Prolog concepts like facts, rules, lists. But still find it hard to use Prolog as a tool to solve logic problems. For example, the following one:

```
Guess the number with following facts:
2741: A digit is right, but it's in the wrong place.
4132: Two digits are right, but it's in the wrong place.
7642: None of the digits are right.
9826: One digit is correct and in the right place.
5079: Two digits are right, one is in the right place and 
      the other is in the wrong place.
```

I manually solved this problem, the answer is 9013. How can I write a Prolog problem to solve this problem? Right now I prefer not using any modules, for learning purposes.

Comment: I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61277541/849891) a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61276283/849891) once. See if it helps any. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Prolog to solve a brain teaser (Master Mind)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276283/using-prolog-to-solve-a-brain-teaser-master-mind)

Comment: @WillNess - Seems like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity almost -- here it's 4-digit numbers, there t's 3. practically the same, yes. I've just found it. :)

Comment: @Enigmativity I meant, I've just found that link, haven't yet thought about whether it's good as a duplicate. looking through it, indeed both answers have the 3 digits hard coded in the code, so, maybe not. :) (?)

Comment: thank you all very much. I will take a look at that brain teaser page, very similar indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalizing my code from the previous [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61276283/849891) about this type of puzzle, we get

```
check( Sol, Guess, NValues-NPlaces ) :-
    findall( t, (member(E, Guess), member(E, Sol)), Values ),
    length( Values, NValues ), 
    maplist( eq, Sol, Guess, NS),
    sum_list( NS, NPlaces).

eq(A,B,X) :- A =:= B -> X=1 ; X=0.

select([X|XS],Dom) :- select(X,Dom,Dom2), select(XS,Dom2).
select([],_).

puzzle( [A,B,C,D] ) :-   
    Dom = [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9],          % using hint 3 
    select( [A,B,C,D], Dom),           % with unique digits
    maplist( check([A,B,C,D]), 
             [[2,7,4,1], [4,1,3,2], [9,8,2,6], [5,0,7,9]],
             [ 1-0,      2-0,       1-1,       2-1      ] ).
```

Trying it out:

```
164 ?- time( puzzle(X) ).
% 33,274 inferences, 0.016 CPU in 0.011 seconds (142% CPU, 2132935 Lips)
X = [9, 0, 1, 3] ;
% 5,554 inferences, 0.016 CPU in 0.002 seconds (780% CPU, 356023 Lips)
false.
```

---

Or we can inline the definitions, fusing them together as

```
mmd(Sol):-
  %%maplist( dif, [2,7,4,1], Sol),         % 1.
  maplist( dif, [4,1,3,2], Sol),           % 2.
  maplist( eq1, Sol, [9,8,2,6], NS4),
                      sum_list( NS4, 1),   % 4.
  maplist( eq1, Sol, [5,0,7,9], NS5),
                      sum_list( NS5, 1),   % 5.
  select( Sol, [0,1,3,5,8,9]),             % 3.

  %%findall( t, (member(E, [2,7,4,1]), member(E, Sol)), [_] ), % 1.
  findall( t, (member(E, [4,1,3,2]), member(E, Sol)), [_,_] ), % 2.
  %%findall( t, (member(E, [9,8,2,6]), member(E, Sol)), [_] ), % 4.
  findall( t, (member(E, [5,0,7,9]), member(E, Sol)), [_,_] ). % 5.

eq1(A,B,C) :- (A#=B,C=1 ; dif(A,B),C=0).
```

rearranging the sub-goals to constrain the search space as much as possible, so the solution is found *almost instantly* and the inferences overall are cut more than in half:

```
167 ?- time( mmd(S) ).
% 1,219 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.001 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
S = [9, 0, 1, 3] ;
% 13,714 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.001 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
false.
```

As was first noticed in the other answer, not all clues are actually needed, and removing them even reduces the number of inferences needed to solve this by some additional small margin.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
% Digits in right place, Digits in wrong place
digit_clue([2, 7, 4, 1], 0, 1).  % Clue is not needed, to decide 9013
digit_clue([4, 1, 3, 2], 0, 2).
digit_clue([7, 6, 4, 2], 0, 0).
digit_clue([9, 8, 2, 6], 1, 0).
digit_clue([5, 0, 7, 9], 1, 1).


go(Solution) :-
    foreach(digit_clue(LstDigits, IntRight, IntWrong),
        add_clue(LstDigits, IntRight, IntWrong, Solution)),
    % Solution is 4 digits (without duplicates) in range 0-9
    element_list_selection([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4, Solution).


add_clue(LstDigits, IntRight, IntWrong, Solution) :-
    count_right_place(LstDigits, IntRight, Solution),
    count_wrong_place(LstDigits, IntWrong, Solution, Solution),
    IntNotPresent is 4 - (IntRight + IntWrong),
    count_not_present(LstDigits, IntNotPresent, Solution, Solution).


% Digit Head, Solution Tail, etc.
count_right_place([], 0, []).
count_right_place([DH|DT], IntRight, [SH|ST]) :-
    succ(IntRight0, IntRight),
    % This is the digit in the Solution
    DH = SH,
    count_right_place(DT, IntRight0, ST).

count_right_place([DH|DT], IntRight, [SH|ST]) :-
    % This is not the digit in the Solution
    dif(DH, SH),
    count_right_place(DT, IntRight, ST).


count_wrong_place([], 0, _Solution, []).
count_wrong_place([DH|DT], IntWrong, Solution, [SH|ST]) :-
    succ(IntWrong0, IntWrong),
    % Digit is in Solution
    member(DH, Solution),
    % ... but not in this position
    dif(DH, SH),
    count_wrong_place(DT, IntWrong0, Solution, ST).

count_wrong_place([_DH|DT], IntWrong, Solution, [_SH|ST]) :-
    % No info to add
    count_wrong_place(DT, IntWrong, Solution, ST).


count_not_present([], 0, _Solution, []).
count_not_present([DH|DT], IntNotPresent, Solution, [_SH|ST]) :-
    succ(IntNotPresent0, IntNotPresent),
    % Digit is not present in Solution
    maplist(dif(DH), Solution),
    count_not_present(DT, IntNotPresent0, Solution, ST).

count_not_present([_DH|DT], IntNotPresent, Solution, [_SH|ST]) :-
    % No info to add
    count_not_present(DT, IntNotPresent, Solution, ST).


% Select IntElements from LstFull (random order, no duplicates)
element_list_selection(LstFull, IntElements, LstSelection) :-
    length(LstSelection, IntElements),
    element_list_selection_(LstSelection, LstFull).

element_list_selection_([], _LstFull).
element_list_selection_([H|T], Lst) :-
    select(H, Lst, Lst0),
    element_list_selection_(T, Lst0).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(findall(Sol, go(Sol), Sols)).
% 53,013 inferences, 0.008 CPU in 0.008 seconds (101% CPU, 6442489 Lips)
Sols = [[9,0,1,3]].
```

Interestingly, the 2741 hint is not needed.